# Error saving credentials: open /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm getting a permissions issue when storing credentials in `config.json` file.

```
Error saving credentials: open /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied
```

I'm using a pipeline to install docker compose:

```
- mkdir -p /home/user/.docker/cli-plugins
- touch /home/user/.docker/config.json
- sudo curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.17.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /home/user/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
- sudo chmod +x /home/user/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
- sudo chown "${USER}":"${USER}" /home/user/.docker -R
- sudo chmod -R g+rw /home/user/.docker
- docker compose version
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this permissions issue as I think the folder has correct permission access. Also, i tried giving full permissions to the config.json file (777) and same issue.

Comment: How are you trying to store credentials?

Comment: @RickRackow As far as I know Docker command line stores its configuration files in a directory called .docker within $HOME directory in a file called config.json. I'm just running `docker login <repo_url> -u <user> -p <pass>`

Comment: If you are unable to access file having 777 access, then I suggest you double check that user, under which you are trying to execute this command has write permissions on parent folders, it can also be the issue

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#privileged-user-requirement `docker login requires user to use sudo or be root, except when:`

Comment: How is this pipeline running? Is the file mounted into the environment? Please provide the output of `ls -al $HOME/.docker/; mount`

Comment: @Mihail2048 by default, without including the part that I'm doing to create the pluguin folder under ./docker the pipeline can store the credentials under ./docker in config.json without any issues. However, I'm thinking that I'm changing some kind of permissions when doing the mkdir -p... and when the pipeline's user wants to store the credentials in the file it fails (even if I change the file's permissions to 777).

Comment: @RickRackowthe script that runs docker login is running with sudo.